# Double Masking on Pandas Dataframe makes RAM explode

Tags: python, pandas, ram, timedelta

The code I have currently works and it works if I only do about 5 iterations but I need to do 500. The loop indicated below was pulling about 100 gig's of RAM usage (on a nice machine) and I cannot figure out why. I suspect it has to do with the double mask I am running (also indicated below)

The "frame" that I am dealing with is not extraordinarily large (by comparison) and consists of 500 stocks and their daily time series prices from 1994 to 2014. What the loop below is doing is picking each stock out of the "frame" and masking that column based on some given dates that vary by stock. Then it takes all of these masked columns and joins them back into a new dataframe (I could not think of an inplace way to do this). I think it is this double mask that is causing the memory to explode. Has anyone else dealt with a problem like this or know how to fix it?

```
frame=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(columns)):
    frame=frame.join(serieslist[i], how='outer', rsuffix=columns[i])
frame2=frame.rename(columns={'PRC': 'PRC'+str(columns[0])})
frame2.to_csv('tester.csv')
frame4=frame2.rename(columns=lambda x: x[3:])

#now chopping it down to 36-1, 24-1 and 12-1
ann_list=data['  DateEffective']

for i in range(len(ann_list)):
    ann_list[i]=parser.parse(ann_list[i])

months36=datetime.timedelta(36*365/12)
############This is the loop that explodes in memory use#################
frame5fin=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(columns)):
    out36=(ann_list[i]+months36)
    ##########I am nearly positive this is the part of the code that makes the RAM explode####
    frame5=frame4[columns[i]][(frame4[columns[i]].index>ann_list[i]) & (frame4[columns[i]].index<out36)]
    print frame5
    frame5fin=frame5fin.join(frame5, how='outer')
print frame5fin.tail(100)
```

Comment: do you really intend to be doing a join between frame5fin and frame5 at the end of the loop? Maybe that should be an append? It seems like after each iteration frame5fin will get exponentially larger.

Comment: @JD Long-

Can you explain why this gets "exponentially larger"? It seems to me like this would be linear. I think this is the crux of my question. Why the exponentiality?

Comment: does the join do what you expect when you test it with a subset of data? Trying to read your code (very hard to do) I am guessing that `frame4` and `frame5` have a number of columns in common as well as a common index. When you join these Pandas tries to match every value in every column. As `frame5in` gets bigger, this join slows down considerably. You are correct that it may be linear decrease in speed. I suspect, however, that you do not want to be joining based on every column. However I find reading your mind to be quite difficult.

Comment: If you want to keep missing values you might consider using the append method then after you're done looping you can take the result and reindex it to add in dates with no data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be accumulating results in the last step:

```
 frame5fin=frame5fin.join(frame5, how='outer')
```

However that code is a join, not appending to the dataframe `frame5fin`.

Possibly you want:

```
 frame5fin=frame5fin.append(frame5)
```

Comment: That would be a possibility but the problem is that each frame5 has a different index. Trying to combine two df's with different indices raises an exception. Do you know any other alternatives by chance?

Comment: hard to imagine this without any example data.... what do you mean by "different index" exactly? What's the index?

Comment: By different indices I mean that the dataframes I am trying to combine do not have a common index between them. For example, one is a time series from June 13,1994 to Aug 1, 2014 while the other is a time series from May, 13, 1998 to Aug 1, 2014. When you join both of these you get a dataframe with an index ranging the union of the two indices (in this case June 13,1994 to Aug 1, 2014) and it will put nans in the second column for anything before May 13, 1998.